# What happens to the propagation mode if a rectangular wave guide is partly covered at the end?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, waveguide

Consider a rectangular waveguide with a TE propagation mode, the end of of waveguide is now covered partly by a conducting material, will its propagation mode change? How will the field lines change?

Answer (score 1):

What can propagate in a waveguide depends on the frequency of the wave and on the waveguide cross-section. The latter determines the cutoff frequency, i.e., that is the minimum frequency of any given mode that can propagate. If more than one mode can propagate then they will if any of those modes are induced by some means. Even if initially only a single mode is launched but the cross-section size is large enough to allow more than one mode to propagate any discontinuity will launch those modes. A conductive partial covering, i.e., a "window" thus will reflect some part of the incident wave and transmit the rest.

If the guide allows more than one mode then both the reflected *and* the transmitted wave will consists of *all* those possibly propagating modes. Around the window, the discontinuity,  there will be some non-propagating energy stored, and if that is more magnetic than electric energy then it is called inductive window, and capacitive if otherwise.

These considerations hold irrespective of whether the window is separating two parts of the same guide or the dimensions change at the discontinuity. If the "other" transmission side very large then it can support almost any frequency and can be considered to be approximately an open-end. Of course, the more modes can propagate the more difficult is to calculate the window.

When multiple modes propagate simultaneously then the field lines of the composite is just the same of the constituent modes via straight vector addition. The great difference is, of course, that the reasonable simpleness of a single mode picture is lost for the composite.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Further to your answer, does the amount of energy stored (magnetic and electric) depend on the propagation mode? i.e. will TE mode store more electrical energy? And covering part of the "window" changes its size, and so cut off frequency changed and thus the allowed mode? Will the reflected wave from the metal plate (covering the window) be in the same mode of the indecent wave?

Comment: Yes but the relative amount of magnetic v. electric energy depends on the mode *and* the the geometry of the window. For example, in a rectangular guide  with a single TE10 mode if the window is parallel with the broad side then it is primarily capacitive but if it is parallel with the narrow side then it is inductive. All this assumes that the window is very thin compared to the *guide* wavelength. A thick window or a slanted one may behave very differently for the same mode, for example it could be resonant, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have a recommended book or website that I can read further?

Comment: Sure, there is an enormous literature on this subject and what to recommend depends on the depth that you wish to sink in... Anyhow, I would start with free and here are three classics: Montgomery, Dicke, Purcell: https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.16056 , Marcuvitz: https://archive.org/details/WaveguideHandbook , and Kurokawa: https://archive.org/details/AnIntroductionToTheTheoryOfMicrowaveCircuits (the pdf file)